# Element won't show() according to variable value and if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to make a blue square show if `fullScreenCropStatus = true` and a red square show if `fullScreenCropStatus = false` once the 'Done' button is clicked.

The variable is correct and is showing the correct value, but the blue square does not show when 'Done' is clicked. I tried `show()`/`hide()` and also the current format of setting the display value in css but neither make the blue square appear.

The red square successfully `hide()` or `display:none`. I am really baffled on this.

The code is below and this is the [JSbin](http://jsbin.com/jabulukoke/edit?html,css,js,console,output)

JS:

```
var fullScreenCrop = false;
var fullScreenCropStatus = false;
$('#cropping--modes').click(function() {
    fullScreenCrop = !fullScreenCrop;
    console.log("fullScreenCrop = " + fullScreenCrop);
});
$("#done").click(function() {
    fullScreenCropStatus = fullScreenCrop;
    console.log("fullScreenCropStatus = " + fullScreenCropStatus);
    if (fullScreenCropStatus === true) {
        $(".done--title__container").css("display", "none");
        $(".done--title__container--fullscreen").css("display", "block");
    } else if (fullScreenCropStatus === false) {
        $(".done--title__container").css("display", "block");
        $(".done--title__container--fullscreen").css("display", "none");
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<button id="cropping--modes">Toggle variable (true/false)</button>
<button id="done">Done</button>

<div class="done--title__container">
<div class="done--title__container--fullscreen">
```

CSS:

```
.done--title__container { display:none; width:50px; height:50px; background-color:red; position:relative; }

.done--title__container--fullscreen { display:none;width:50px; height:50px; background-color:blue; position:relative; }

#cropping--modes { display:block; width:200px; height:30px; }

#done { display:block; width:200px; height:30px; }
```

Comment: Your `div` tags aren't closed. It works fine once you close them.

Comment: Your div tags "done--title__container" and "done--title__container--fullscreen" are not closed. Everything is working fine if you fix that

Comment: Well, I'm going to retreat into a dark hole and wonder why I didn't spot that during 2 hours trying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Close the div tags and you're fine:

```
<button id="cropping--modes">Toggle variable (true/false)</button>
<button id="done">Done</button>

<div class="done--title__container"></div>
<div class="done--title__container--fullscreen"></div>
```

Comment: Oh my gosh you are kidding me! How was I blind to that haha thank you, I'm off to the opticians.

Comment: One of many reason we always ask people to show ALL their code including markup!